# ReactNative If the contents are long,TextInput will be white

Tags: react-native

React Native 0.61.4

It doesn't happen on Android 7 and 9.

`Android 8` Only, TextInput turns white when it exceeds a certain length.

When it exceeds a certain length, it turns white and when you erase a letter, it comes back. After that, enter the text again, and if it exceeds the length, it becomes white.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind give us your snippet?

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon 
I want to upload the code, but it is difficult because there is so much code that is not related to TextInput.

Comment: Have try to play with size? Anyway, I gave you upvote and hopefully you will solve it  or work around soon.

Answer (score 0):

This bug occurs when there is a `TextInput` in the `scrollView`.
Fixed after changing `ScrollView` to `View`.